# Updating javascript object property?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I have a structure like the following:

```
skillet.person = {
  name: {
    first: '',
    last: ''
  }, 
  age: {
    current: '' 
  },
  birthday: {
    day: '',
    month: '',
    year: ''
  }
}
```

I was wondering how I would update these values ? i.e. I thought the following was correct

```
skillet.person.name.push({ first: 'blah', last: 'ha'});
```

but it's wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: MDN has a great JavaScript tutorial, especially https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to mix an object into another one, you can use jQuery's deep extend function. "Deep" means that it does not overwrite `name` with the new object, but rather overwrites the properties inside such an object.

```
$.extend(true, skillet.person, {
  name: {
    first: 'updated'
  },
  birthday: {
    day: 'updated',
    year: 'updated'
  }
});
```

Now, `skillet.person` has the appropriate properties updated, while the other properties are untouched.

Answer (score 117):

Using ES7+ syntax and a functional approach:

```
const new_obj = { ...obj, name: { first: 'blah', last: 'ha'} }
```

Comment: what about ```const new_obj = { ...obj, name: { first: 'blah'} }```? I missed the ```last``` property!

Comment: I that way, you're removing the `last` property. If you want to update just the `first` property (without deleting the `last` property), you should do `const new_obj = { ...obj, name: { ...obj.name, first: 'blah'} }`.

Comment: This spread operator with an object works in React for setting State as well.

Comment: is `...obj` supposed to be replaced with `skillet.person` in this example?  Or `...skillet.person`?

Answer (score 39):

On recent browsers with **ECMAScript 2015**, you can do:

```
Object.assign(skillet.person.name, { first: 'blah', last: 'ha'});
```

which will preserve any existing attribute not listed in the right object.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

[EDIT] With **ES7**, you can do even shorter (but is it clearer?...):

```
{...skillet.person.name, ...{ first: 'blah', last: 'ha'}};
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: There is a small difference in the second choice, the property(ie. functions) will not be preserved in the second choice.

Comment: Are you not recreating the object from scratch with the second choice?  I believe that would be greater overhead.

Answer (score 34):

As @ramon-diogo wrote with ES7+

I like to update nested values like:

```js
let user = {
    name: {
        first: 'john',
        last: 'smith'
    },
    age: 18,
    city: 'new york'
}

const age = 20;

user = {...user, age}

console.log(user.age)
// output: 20


const newData ={
    age: 22,
    city: 'san francisco'
};

user = {...user,...newData}

console.log(user.name.first)
// output: john
console.log(user.age)
// output: 22
console.log(user.city)
// output: 'san francisco'
```

Comment: this is the only generic answer that can be applied for any use case

Answer (score 29):

```
skillet.person.name.first = "blah"
skillet.person.name.last = "ha"
```

or

```
skillet.person.name = {first : "blah", last : "ha"}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. is there a faster way to update instead of listing each and every value if I dont want to replace the property if not all the values are available ?

Comment: @Andy: You may be looking for an `extend` function. [See Underscore.js for an implementation.](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#extend)

Comment: @pimvdb - yeah at the moment I have a heap of properties but not all contain values. I was replacing the object with only partial properities and it was causing a prob - does this mean I must list each value like MrE has done or is there a faster way without replacing ?

Comment: @Andy: Do you have two objects of which the properties you want to blend together?

Comment: @pimvdb - i just have like an object with 9 properties but only usually update 6 of them. I tried `{ ... }` but it will replace the 3 unfilled vals - so it means i must write 6 properties like `skillet.person.name.first` etc ?

Comment: @pimvdb The link to the [Underscore.js documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) has changed.

Answer (score 5):

`push` is a method of `Array`s that adds a new item to an array.

If you want to replace the value then:

```
skillet.person.name = { … };
```

If you want to store multiple (full) names in the object, then you'll need the property to hold an array of objects instead of a single object.

Comment: thanks is there a faster way to update instead of listing each and every value if I dont want to replace ?

Comment: @Andy: You can iterate over object properties. `for(var prop in newValues) { oldValues[prop] = newValues[prop];}` (in a gist). MDN also has a good page about `for...in`. Have a look at it.

Answer (score 4):

I think that is simpler

```
     let skillet = {
        person: {
            name    : {
                first: '',
                last : ''
            },
            age     : {
                current: ''
            },
            birthday: {
                day  : '',
                month: '',
                year : ''
            }
        }
    };

    let update = {
        person: {
            name: {
                first: 'blah',
                last : 'ha'
            }
        }
    };

    let result = Object.assign(skillet.person, update.person);

    console.log(result);
```

Comment: What if I just have to update 'last' without affecting 'first'?

Comment: Following the same example as platie, I think the easiest way to edit only one element is this way:
.
.

skillet.person.birthday.year = 2019
console.log({...skillet.person, ...skillet.person.birthday.year});

Answer (score 1):

```
skillet.person.name.first = "blah"
skillet.person.name.last = "ha"
```

The easiest way.

Answer (score -1):

```
skillset.person.name = {};
```

This is the easiest way to assign value to the property of an object.

Comment: It looks almost like Quentin's answer in 2012. Are there any improvements or changes?