# Update the value property of 'costElement' to the calculated cost

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck getting this program to work. I added a switch statement to determine the cost and I believe the rest is right I just don't know how to update cost in the text field. I checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454863/updating-javascript-object-property/48209957) and a few more but have been unable to find answers. Any guidance is appreciated thanks.

[ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em4jI.png)

**membership.html**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="theForm">
  <fieldset><legend>Create Your Membership</legend>
        <p>Complete this form to calculate your membership. There's a 20% discount if you enroll for more than one year!</p>
        <div><label for="type">Type</label> <select name="type" id="type" required>
            <option value="basic">Basic - $10.00</option>
            <option value="premium">Premium - $15.00</option>
            <option value="gold">Gold - $20.00</option>
            <option value="platinum">Platinum - $25.00</option>
        </select></div>
        <div><label for="years">Years</label><input type="number" name="years" id="years" min="1" required></div>
        <div><label for="cost">Cost</label><input type="text" name="cost" id="cost" disabled></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**membership.js**

```
function calculate() {
    // Be strict:
    'use strict';

    // Variable to store the total cost:
    var cost;

    // Get a reference to the form elements:
    var type = document.getElementById('type');
    var years = document.getElementById('years');

    // TODO Convert the year to a number:
    var years = parseInt("1996");

    // Check for valid data:
    if (type && type.value && years && (years > 0)) {

        // TODO Add a switch statement to determine the base cost using the value of "type"
        switch(cost) {
          case "basic":
          text = "$10.00";
          break;
          case "premium":
          text = "$15.00";
          break;
          case "gold":
          text = "$20.00";
          break;
          case "platinum":
          text = "$25.00";
          break;
        }
        // TODO Update cost to factor in the number of years:

        // Discount multiple years:
        if (years > 1) {
            cost *= .20; // 20%
        }

        var costElement = document.getElementById('cost');

        // TODO update the value property of 'costElement' to the calculated cost
        var costElement = type + years;
    } else { // Show an error:
        document.getElementById('cost').value = 'Please enter valid values.';
    }

    // Return false to prevent submission:
    return false;
}

function init() {
    'use strict';
    // call a function named calculate() when form submitted
    document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = calculate;
}
window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this line:

`var years = document.getElementById('years');`

...followed by this line?

`var years = parseInt("1996");`

First of all, why is this a calendar year instead of a number of years (surely you aren't pricing a membership that will last for nearly two millennia)?

Anyway, this line simply sticks the value "1996" into the variable `years`, it does **not** update the element with an `id` of `years` to 1996. Same problem here:

`var costElement = type + years;`

The variable `costElement` has already be declared, and this line replaces its previous value (which in the element in the HTML document) with `type + years`. And `type + years` doesn't make a lot of sense, since you want to multiply, not add.

Then you got this mysterious bit:

```
        // Discount multiple years:
        if (years > 1) {
            cost *= .20; // 20%
        }
```

`cost` has never been defined, so what's `cost` becoming 20% of? Besides, I'm pretty sure you want to take 20% off the final price, not make the final price 20% of the original cost -- because that would be an 80% discount!

This should be more like:

```
        var cost = 1;
        // Discount multiple years:
        if (years > 1) {
            cost = 0.80; // 20% off
        }
```

Further, you need some way to turn the value ('basic', 'premium', etc.) into a numeric value for calculation. You could just add to your `switch` statement for that, but you already have `text`, and stripping off the leading `$` will do to get a number, so you can do this:

`var price = parseFloat(text.substr(1));`

Now you can get the total cost like this (notice you don't need to, and shouldn't, put `var` in front again):

`cost *= price * years;`

Then, with some appropriate formatting, you can display value this way:

`costElement.value = '$' + cost.toFixed(2);`

I don't know if that fixes everything, and there are also better ways to display a value than using a disabled input field (like setting the `innerText` property of a `<span>`), but hopefully this can get you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call value property of your input (type is also a node element, you need to use value property of it to get chosen option)

```
costElement.value = type.value + years;
```