# Update variable to show total cost

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck getting this program to work. I'm trying to get the output to to look like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GohWV.png, where if the years is > 1 then the discount is automatically applied. I've tried looking at different threads like this one [Updating javascript object property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454863/updating-javascript-object-property/48209957) with the case switches, but no help.

**HTML**

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Membership Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" id="theForm">
            <script src="js/membership.js"></script>
            <fieldset><legend>Create Your Membership</legend>
                <p>Complete this form to calculate your membership. There's a 20% discount if you enroll for more than one year!</p>
                <div><label for="type">Type</label> <select name="type" id="type" required>
                    <option value="basic">Basic - $10.00</option>
                    <option value="premium">Premium - $15.00</option>
                    <option value="gold">Gold - $20.00</option>
                    <option value="platinum">Platinum - $25.00</option>
                </select></div>
                <div><label for="years">Years</label><input type="number" name="years" id="years" min="1" required></div>
                <div><label for="cost">Cost</label><input type="text" name="cost" id="cost" disabled></div>
                <input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="submit">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

***JS***

```
     'use strict';
        
        
        function calculate() {
          
            //declares a variable named 'cost' to store the total cost:
            var cost;
        
            // lookup the type and years input elements with DOM getElementById()
            var type = document.getElementById("type");
            var years = document.getElementById("years");
        
            // Convert the year to a number()), i'm not sure if this is working or not 
            if (years && years.value) {
                years = parseInt(years.value, 10);
            }
        
            // Check for valid data:
            if (type && type.value && years && (years > 0)) {
        
                // Add a switch statement to determine the base cost using the value of "type"
                switch (type.value) {
                    case 'basic':
                        cost = "$10.00";
                    break;
                case 'premium':
                    cost = "$15.00";
                    break;
                case 'gold':
                    cost = "$20.00";
                    break;
                case 'platinum':
                    cost = "$25.00";
                    break;
            }
    
            // Update cost by multiplying number of years
            cost = cost * years;
            // Discount multiple years
            if (years > 1) {
                cost *= 0.80; // 80%
            }
    
            let costElement = document.getElementById('cost');
    
            // onvert cost to a number and then format to decimal places (see Number.toFixed())
             cost = parseFloat(cost.substr(1));
            //update the value property of 'costElement' to the calculated cost
        }       costElement = type + cost;
        // Return false to prevent submission:
        return false;
    }
    function init() {
        document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = calculate;
    }
    window.onload = init;
```

Comment: What problem u are facing? Any errors?

Comment: You have this defined   cost = cost * years; but cost is a string . Try setting cost to just a number

Comment: When I run the code, nothing happens? I'm not sure where the error is

Comment: where did u called calculate() function?

Comment: at the bottom with init()

Comment: Did u check the console logs? Have u tried debugging it on yourself first?

Comment: @Zurez I got a function to convert cost into a number.
  // TODO convert cost to a number and then format to decimal places
         cost = parseFloat(cost.substr(1));

Comment: @santosh yes I have, I think there's error in the logic itself here, I might be overthinking it

Comment: Azura, you convert cost later on. But at the time of execution, the line of `cost = cost * years;` is run first. At this point, cost is a string that you are trying to multiply. Make sure you are using numbers and not string when trying to use mathematical expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot perform math on string. In the switch case, you were setting like `cost = "$10.00"`. You were then doing `cost *= 0.8` which would result in `NaN`, since you were multiplying a string.
You can set cost to a Number, perform all operations and add "$" and ".00" after it.

It will be `costElement.value` and not just `costElement = ...` (also, it was out of if condition, which resulted in `costElement` being `undefined`.)

(Note: I have changed `input[type="submit"]` to `input[type="button"]` in HTML for demo purposes, to prevent submission.)

```js
'use strict';


function calculate() {

  //declares a variable named 'cost' to store the total cost:
  var cost;

  // lookup the type and years input elements with DOM getElementById()
  var type = document.getElementById("type");
  var years = document.getElementById("years");

  // Convert the year to a number()), i'm not sure if this is working or not 
  if (years && years.value) {
    years = parseInt(years.value, 10);
  }

  // Check for valid data:
  if (type && type.value && years && (years > 0)) {

    // Add a switch statement to determine the base cost using the value of "type"
    switch (type.value) {
      case 'basic':
        cost = 10;
        break;
      case 'premium':
        cost = 15;
        break;
      case 'gold':
        cost = 20;
        break;
      case 'platinum':
        cost = 25;
        break;
    }

    // Update cost by multiplying number of years
    cost = cost * years;
    // Discount multiple years
    if (years > 1) {
      cost *= 0.80; // 80%
    }
    cost = "$" + cost + ".00";
    let costElement = document.getElementById('cost');

    //update the value property of 'costElement' to the calculated cost
    costElement.value = cost; //You can also use type.value + cost
  }
  // Return false to prevent submission:
  return false;
}

function init() {
  document.getElementById('submit').onclick = calculate; //replace with document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = calculate;
}
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Membership Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form action="" method="post" id="theForm">
    <script src="js/membership.js"></script>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Create Your Membership</legend>
      <p>Complete this form to calculate your membership. There's a 20% discount if you enroll for more than one year!</p>
      <div><label for="type">Type</label>
        <select name="type" id="type" required>
          <option value="basic">Basic - $10.00</option>
          <option value="premium">Premium - $15.00</option>
          <option value="gold">Gold - $20.00</option>
          <option value="platinum">Platinum - $25.00</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div><label for="years">Years</label><input type="number" name="years" id="years" min="1" required></div>
      <div><label for="cost">Cost</label><input type="text" name="cost" id="cost" disabled></div>
      <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="submit">

    </fieldset>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are n mumber of bugs involved.

Please find the details

- Use `e.preventDefault()` inside the form submit to prevent page reload while submitting the form.
- Inside the switch cases, set the value of `cost` as number rather than string
- Donot declare `let costElement = document.getElementById('cost');` inside the `if` because you are making use of it outside if. `let` created scope blocked variables which can be accessed inside the code block where its defined. So the variable will not ba variable outside if.
- You should assing the input value using `costElement.value = type.value + cost;` where `costElement` is your input selected using `id`.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
function calculate(e) {
  // To prevent page reload
  e.preventDefault();

  //declares a variable named 'cost' to store the total cost:
  var cost;

  // lookup the type and years input elements with DOM getElementById()
  var type = document.getElementById("type");
  var years = document.getElementById("years");

  // Convert the year to a number()), i'm not sure if this is working or not 
  if (years && years.value) {
    years = parseInt(years.value, 10);
  }

  // Check for valid data:
  if (type && type.value && years && (years > 0)) {

    // Add a switch statement to determine the base cost using the value of "type"
    switch (type.value) {
      case 'basic':
        cost = 10.00;
        break;
      case 'premium':
        cost = 15.00;
        break;
      case 'gold':
        cost = 20.00;
        break;
      case 'platinum':
        cost = 25.00;
        break;
    }

    // Update cost by multiplying number of years
    cost = cost * years;
    // Discount multiple years
    if (years > 1) {
      cost *= 0.80; // 80%
    }

    // Cannot declare here `let` will create scope blocked elements
    // let costElement = document.getElementById('cost');

    // onvert cost to a number and then format to decimal places (see Number.toFixed())
    // cost = parseFloat(cost.substr(1));
    //update the value property of 'costElement' to the calculated cost
  }    
  let costElement = document.getElementById('cost');
  costElement.value = type.value + cost;
  // Return false to prevent submission:
  return false;
}
function init() {
  document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = calculate;
}
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" id="theForm">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Create Your Membership</legend>
    <p>Complete this form to calculate your membership. There's a 20% discount if you enroll for more than one year!
    </p>
    <div><label for="type">Type</label> <select name="type" id="type" required>
        <option value="basic">Basic - $10.00</option>
        <option value="premium">Premium - $15.00</option>
        <option value="gold">Gold - $20.00</option>
        <option value="platinum">Platinum - $25.00</option>
      </select></div>
    <div><label for="years">Years</label><input type="number" name="years" id="years" min="1" required></div>
    <div><label for="cost">Cost</label><input type="text" name="cost" id="cost" disabled></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" id="submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```